# SIM cards in South America, which are the most reliable ones?

Tags: cellphones, internet, south-america, communication

I know that this sounds very subjective but I don't know how to put it different:

I will be travel in South America for few months, with an average timespan of 2 weeks in each of this countries: Argentina, Chile, Bolivia, Peru, Ecuador and Colombia.

Talking about SIM cards, is anyone who travaled a similar journey and can tell which is the better option between buying a SIM card in each country or just buy one for all of them (or some of them)?

I would like something with good signal/coverage, 5 GB/month or similar and some voice (100 minutes of domestic calls should be fine).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Definitely not the Claro from Ecuador. I had no luck roaming with it in any country. In Panama, Claro were advertising Latin-American wide roaming but it would be good to know which SA country sells such a card.

Comment: For clarity, it's not the SIM that matters, it's the *provider and plan*.  What you're looking for is a plan that offers data and preferably voice roaming across the continent.

Comment: You probably are best off buying a sim for each country.